# If maxSelectedItems is set for multiple items, disable typing more text in input

Tags: angular, npm, angular-ngselect

When I use a multi select with maxSelectedItems like in demos below, after reaching max items selected it should not allow user to type more text into the select.

https://ng-select.github.io/ng-select#/multiselect

Answer (score 1):

You can limit the maximum selected items by adding a 'maxSelectedItems' attribute .
example,

```
<ng-select
    #select
    [items]="people$ | async"
    [multiple]="true"
    [maxSelectedItems]="3"
    bindLabel="name"
    [(ngModel)]="selectedPeople">
</ng-select>
```

here is the stackblitz for the same,
[StackBlitz for maximumselected items](https://stackblitz.com/run?file=src%2Fmulti-select-limit-example.component.html).

The ng-select gets disabled and doesn't allow to type more if the limit is reached.